# httpmodule not initialized even after adding modules under system.webserver

Tags: model-view-controller, httpmodule, iis-8

I am trying to use HttpModules in Asp.Net MVC 4 application. The IIS version is 8. But the HttpModule is not getting hit. Only solution that I see everywhere is to add modules section under system.webserver section in config. But its still not working.

Is there anything that I am missing here. Please help.

Comment: any error, can we see the web.config?

Comment: If it doesn't raise the error, that happened to me once when a module was placed in App_Code and it didn't compile, so I had to open properties for the file and set Build Action to "Compile". Maybe this is the issue?